# Ember.js computed property filter hasMany array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to filter the contents of a ember-data 'hasMany' field.  My model has some subquestions, which I want to filter into a property 'childOptions' on my controller and display in the template using

```
{{#each childOptions}}stuff{{/each}}
```

When I put this on my controller, it works and the each iterates over appropriate values:

```
childOptions: Ember.computed.filterBy('model.subquestions', 'surveyQuestionType.name', 'childOption'),
```

However when I do this, nothing is shown.

```
childOptions: Ember.computed.filter('model.subquestions', function(subquestion) {
    return subquestion.get('surveyQuestionType.name') === 'childOption';
}),
```

'surveyQuestionType' is a DS.belongsTo that exists on the model for 'subquestions', and it has a 'name' property.

I want to understand why the 'filterBy' method works, while the 'filter' method does not (so that I can use 'filter' for more complex queries in the future).  I think it has something to do with promises, and the `subquestion.get('property')` syntax that I am using inside the filter function.

EDIT:

This is the model:

```
App.SurveyQuestion = DS.Model.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {
    surveyQuestionType: DS.belongsTo('surveyQuestionType', { async: true }),
    display: DS.belongsTo('surveyQuestionDisplay', { async: true, inverse: 'surveyQuestion' }),
    sortOrder: DS.attr('number'),
    parent: DS.belongsTo('surveyQuestion', { async: true, inverse: 'subquestions' }),
    parentDependencyCriteria: DS.attr('string'),
    required: DS.attr('boolean'),
    surveySections: DS.hasMany('surveySectionQuestion', { async: true, inverse: 'surveyQuestion' }),
    subquestions: DS.hasMany('surveyQuestion', { async: true, inverse: 'parent' })
});
```

Comment: `subquestion.get('surveyQuestionType.name')` returns `undefined`, which I am pretty sure is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it!  If I do a simple `{{#each subquestions}}{{surveyQuestionType.name}}{{/each}}` in my template I can see the property just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of ember-data 1.0.0-beta.11, promises seem to be working smoother and I had success with this (I actually went with a different approach for my original problem, but used this code in a similar situation):

```
childOptions: function() {
    var subquestions = this.get('subquestions');
    if (subquestions) {
        return subquestions.filter(function(subquestion) {    
            var surveyQuestion = subquestion.get('surveyQuestion');
            return (surveyQuestion && surveyQuestion.get('name') === 'childOptions');
        });
    }
}.property('subquestions.@each.surveyQuestion')
```

The `.property('subquestions.@each.surveyQuestion')` causes the property to be updated when the `surveyQuestion` promise resolves.  If you put some output, you will see that initially the property gets called and `subquestions` will be null.

Comment: The "if (subquestions)" be ignored and add a .property("childOptions") where every you use the function. didn't test it but should work. I used .any  instead of filter and it works.

Answer (score 5):

I have spent more time discovering this category of issue with my own work than I care to admit, but fortunately the solution is straightforward.  In your `DS.Model` definition, is `surveyQuestionType` a `belongsTo` relationship with `{async: true}`?  If so, that's your issue.

Whenever you set a relationship in your `DS.Model` as `{async: true}`, you can think of it as actually setting a **promise** that you will eventually get that property.  This makes sense and becomes intuitive, but it's not documented very well!

Promises are especially tricky for beginners because your Handlebars template will transparently handle `{{surveyQuestionType.name}}` whether `surveyQuestionType` is a concrete value or a promise.  That confuses beginners because you can't tell at first blush if Handlebars is rendering a concrete value or a promise.

When you're dealing with a promise, you can directly access what that promise resolves to in its `content` property.  In fact, you can even set that `content` property, too.  But be careful with this because reading/writing directly to the `content` property has no effect on any pending operations that promise may have.  So if the promise is still pending while you write to its `content` value, your write will get overwritten once it resolves.

I write directly to the `content` property when I'm adding a new entity and need to populate a promise relationship.  It makes sense there, but if I were reading a value, I would need to find some way to guarantee for myself that the promise had already resolved when I was reading the `content` property...or, I could let Handlebars handle this directly, knowing that for pure display logic I don't care about a delay of 150 ms.

Anyway, if everything above is applicable to your issue, here's how you can edit your code to get this working:

```
childOptions: Ember.computed.filter('model.subquestions', function(subquestion) {
    return subquestion.get('surveyQuestionType.content.name') === 'childOption';
})
```

**UPDATE #1:** I believe I just violated my own recommendation by not accessing `content` thoughtfully.  See my comments for info on debugging, and you might also try this:

```
childOptions: Ember.computed.filter('model.subquestions', function(subquestion) {
    return subquestion.get('surveyQuestionType').then( function( model ) {
       return model.get('name') === 'childOption';
    });
})
```

**UPDATE #2:** See my comments below and in particular https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1865.  this turns out to be a trickier issue, and I would welcome the input of others to clarify the best approach here.

I have solved this problem in my own code by handling promises upstream so that I can directly access the `content` property or not deal with promises at all in my filters.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and you are correct about `async: true`.  Your answer doesn't quite work though.  It could be that the subquestions property is also a promise array.  Also, isn't the `.property()` addition unnecessary when using `Ember.computed.filter`?  Ideally I want something that filters after the promise is resolved, right?

Comment: Re: `.property()`, you're correct and thx for pointing that out. I'll update my answer.  Will respond to other points shortly.

Comment: Re: this not working, I have two thoughts. (1) It's helpful to know exactly what each entity you're dealing with is. So, try `console.log(this.get('model.subquestions').toString())` This will tell you if it's a promise or concrete value. You should also look at the excellent http://eviltrout.com/2014/08/16/debugging-ember-js.html. (2) I may have made a mistake in my original answer because I accessed content from a promise, but that code does not wait until the promise is resolved to read the value. Check out the updated answer. Sorry about the errors in the original response.

Comment: Returning a value within the `then` accomplishes nothing. This will end up filtering on the value of the promise (which will always be true).

Comment: Ok, using async in filters turns out to be a much trickier issue than I first realized. See https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1865. Personally, I have solved this by resolving my promises further upstream. My answer addresses part of the problem but doesn't give you the full solution.